# update row with array items into database php

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am trying to update a record in my database with values pulled from an exploded array

```
    $arr2 = explode(",",$_POST['hidden-tags']); 
   //echo $arr2[0];

   //insert new rows into blog post
    mysql_select_db($db, $db);
 $insertq = mysql_query("UPDATE blog SET tags1 = $arr2[0],tags2 = $arr2[1],tags3 = $arr2[2], tags4 = $arr2[3], tags5 = $arr2[4]  WHERE idblog = '$id' ",$dbconnet);
```

If I echo the values from my array one at a time it works great.  Once I try to put them in the db the row turns up empty.  Whats more the user may not of entered 5 items they may only have entered 1 but I dont think thats really the problem.  To be honest I cant see why its currently failing at all.

I know I can save all values in one field but it will be easier as separate fieldsfor when I  pull back and query later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the data types of the columns are string, values must be wrap with single quotes as they are string literals. eg,

```
$insertq = mysql_query("UPDATE blog SET tags1 = '". $arr2[0] . "',....");
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Data has already been sanitised by this point which is why there is no sql injection protection. Your answer solved my issue.  Cant believe I overlooked '".."' as thats something I already knew.  Time for a break maybe

Comment: Im using dreamweaver built in functions so GetvalueString($VALUE, "text")

Answer (score 1):

```
$insertq = mysql_query("UPDATE blog SET tags1 = $arr2[0],tags2 = $arr2[1],tags3 = $arr2[2], tags4 = $arr2[3], tags5 = $arr2[4]  WHERE idblog = '$id' ",$dbconnet);
```

should be:

```
$insertq = mysql_query("UPDATE blog SET tags1 = '".$arr2[0]."',tags2 = '".$arr2[1]."',tags3 = '".$arr2[2]."', tags4 = '".$arr2[3]."', tags5 = '".$arr2[4]."'  WHERE idblog = '".$id."' ,$dbconnet);
```

or the whole query is going to consider the variables names as part of the string

EDITED: i had the quotes inverted.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this :

```
$insertq = mysql_query("UPDATE blog SET tags1 = "'.$arr2[0].'",tags2 = "'.$arr2[1].'",tags3 = "'.$arr2[2].'", tags4 = "'.$arr2[3].'", tags5 = "'.$arr2[4].'"  WHERE idblog = "'.$id.'" ",$dbconnet);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to look at the datatypes of your table. If you are using varchar or text as data-types then single colon will be necessary.

```
$insertq = mysql_query("UPDATE blog SET tags1 =' $arr2[0]',tags2 = '$arr2[1]',tags3 = '$arr2[2]', tags4 = '$arr2[3]', tags5 = '$arr2[4]'  WHERE idblog = '$id' ",$dbconnet);
```

Also if the **idblog** is integer then donot use single quotes.

hope this helps